# What to do now that asihttprequest's owner stopped working on the project?

Tags: asihttprequest

Now that the owner of ASIHTTPRequest is no longer working on the library, is there another alternative that is as good as this library?

Or maybe will the repository from their [github](https://github.com/pokeb/asi-http-request) be updated? By, maybe someone else who is well educated about the project (At least someone knowledgeable will still continue to work on it)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at https://github.com/pokeb/asi-http-request/commits/master you'll see that it has been updated since the owner stopped working on it...

Comment: i edited my question title, thanks mate, i didn't know there's a way to view the commit history in github, thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend AFNetworking as the best supported option for a general networking library

http://afnetworking.com

If you are mainly working with a RESTful API, then RestKit is a great library to use instead of writing your own glue code:

http://restkit.org